# Abuse of notation in GR? $f(x)$ vs. $(f \circ \psi^{-1})(x)$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, notation

I see some GR books write $f(x)$ (or even $f(x^\mu)$) when talking about a function on a manifold. But with $f: M \to \mathbb R$ and coordinates defined by a chart $\psi: M \to \mathbb R^n$, shouldn't the notation rather be $(f \circ \psi^{-1})(x)$ when evaluating $f$ at the point corresponding to $x$? The only one I see write it like this is Wald; even Carroll, who uses a chart construction similar to Wald's, writes it the first way a lot.

Is this simply a common abuse of notation, or am I actually missing something?

Comment: It's pure laziness, or perhaps a desire to save ink/electrons, page-space, or brain-cycles.

Comment: Abuse of notation is not something from GR. It is actually everywhere in Physics and in a sense, as @mikestone says, it's pure laziness. After a while you get used to it, and start using it yourself (it saves ink/electrons, page-space, brain-cycles and keeps you from needing to think of more letters). The underlying idea is that what the notation means is clear from context. Anyway, if at any time you are unsure you can always "unpack things" and write in a more precise notation as mathematicians do to figure it out what was intended.

Comment: Here is a related question from myself when I was back in second year in undergraduate school and, more inclined to pure math at the time, felt this kind of thing completely absurd: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78542/how-to-deal-with-the-notation-of-a-function-f-vs-its-value-fx-in-physics

Comment: Who says that $x\in R^n$ and not $x\in M$?

Comment: @mmeent Well, the authors themselves do when they define coordinate systems through charts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an abuse of notation.  If the chart is given by $(U,x)$ with $x:M\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ the chart map, then for each $p\in U\subseteq M$ we have
$$f(p) = \bigg(f\circ x^{-1}\bigg)\big(x(p)\big) \equiv f_x\big(x(p)\big)$$
where $f_x :\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the local expression of $f$ in the chart $x$.  When working with functions on manifolds, one almost always works at the chart level with such objects like $f_x$ with the understanding that they "lift" to a well-defined function $f$ at the manifold level. Of course, there are objects appear in charts which do *not* exhibit this behavior, such as the connection coefficients $\Gamma$. These objects are *only* defined in a chart, and are not tensorial in nature.

In any case, in my opinion it's pedagogically very important to make the distinction between functions on a manifold and functions in a chart. Once the issue is fully understood, I might be tempted to relax a bit and write fewer symbols, with clarifications added as necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I fully agree with your final paragraph. I can certainly see the merits of a compressed notation for computations, but it should be made clear to the reader what it actually means. I also think one might revert to the full, detailed, notation for proofs and derivations, where mapping out the various functional dependencies is especially important.